# Executing database table creation once plugin is activated

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am running into some trouble with how I am calling my function to execute the creation of tables into the database.
I created a WordPress plugin and when I activate the plugin I am supposed to create the necessary tables in the database for the plugin.

This is the code I currently have in my `plugin.php`

```
include 'schema.php';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_schema');
```

This is what my `schema.php` looks like

```
<?php
function create_schema(){
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    $market_information   = $table_prefix . 'market_information';

     if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$market_information'") != $market_information){
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $market_information(
            id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
            market_id int,
            `key` varchar(150),
            value varchar(500),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
    .....
```

With what I have I get the exception that extra characters where passed into the headers.
When I fix my `register_activation_hook` to:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('schema', 'create_schema'));
```

I don't get the exception message but I also don't get the 'Plugin Activated' message and I do not see the tables created in the database.

How can I fix for activation_hook so my schema file runs and my tables get created properly?

Comment: Where is `$market_information` defined? I think that could be an issue.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal no i have it defined i just forgot to copy it over.

Comment: @bluePearl Why don't use the tools in the database to check the table? For example, CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $market_information

Comment: you can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`